# Dygraph: Two YAxis some series stacked some not

Tags: dygraphs

Is it possible to create a chart with some lines are stacked at each other (Y axis on the left) and others are not stacked (Y2 axis on the right)?

And I would like to get some Lines filled under the chart and other in the same graph not.

Is there an example anywhere? I havent found one.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible. The problem falls under [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/dygraphs/issues/detail?id=126) ("support more per-axis options"). Feel free to star that issue (or take a stab at fixing it!).